# Electron.js Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to make a new Electron desktop app.
by the way, when I insert electron module, I get this error.
If you are familiar with electron, can you help me to resolve this error?

I already tried to fix it.
include require.js.
but not working yet.

```
<script>
    const electron = require('electron'); // I get error at this line.
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

    function submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Electron` 5.0, then [nodeIntegration is false by default](https://electronjs.org/blog/electron-5-0#security-improvements) in `BrowserWindows` so you need to specify it explicitly when you create your window:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install electron

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

`--save-dev` because electron is an development dependency.